# Browsing sites with their domain name from the same server they are hosted on

Tags: iis-6, windows-server-2008

I have a co-located webserver(Win2k8) having a public IP and have hosted my ASP.NET website on the IIS. Though, I am able to browse everything else from the local browser(IE) installed on the server, the server somehow fails to browse the websites that are hosted in its own IIS when I access them using their 'domain name' set as a host header. For e.g: If the website is for "www.mywebsite.com", so naturally I have set the Host header property to "www.mywebsite.com" and when I put "www.mywebsite.com" in my IE address bar it fails to get the request.

Ok, so now why I need to access this website is that, I plan to send a Query parameter to one of the pages from another page of the same website.

Any idea how to get this working? Thanks in advance folks.

Comment: Two ideas - Have you specified which IP address(es) IIS is listening on for that host header? And what IP address is returned if you run "nslookup www.mywebsite.com" from a command line?

Comment: Thx DTU. Regarding your first question the answer is "Default" and for the other it correctly finds out the appropriate server IP address once I do nslookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be trying to reach itself via its public IP address, which it may not be able to route to.

You can try adding a line into your hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts, or equivalent) as follows:

```
127.0.0.1   www.mywebsite.com
```

Which will force it to access it via the loopback adapter.